# Linking *.lib files with MinGW

Tags: linker, mingw

Is it possible to Link `*.lib` files with MinGW (I use it with Eclipse)?

I'm fighting with libcurl+OpenSSL and I don't understand if my errors are because I try to use `.lib`-files in MinGW or something else is wrong:

```
..\lib/libeay32.lib(tmp32/asn_mime.obj):(.text[_SMIME_text]+0x6): undefined reference to `_chkstk'
..\lib/libeay32.lib(tmp32/asn_mime.obj):(.text[_SMIME_text]+0xb): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
..\lib/libeay32.lib(tmp32/asn_mime.obj):(.text[_SMIME_text]+0x63): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
..\lib/libeay32.lib(tmp32/asn_mime.obj):(.text[_SMIME_text]+0x19e): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
..\lib/libeay32.lib(tmp32/ech_ossl.obj):(.text[_ecdh_compute_key]+0x6): undefined    reference to `_chkstk'
..\lib/libeay32.lib(tmp32/bio_asn1.obj):(.text[_asn1_bio_set_ex]+0x6): undefined reference to `_chkstk'
..\lib/libeay32.lib(tmp32/bio_asn1.obj):(.text[_asn1_bio_get_ex]+0x6): undefined reference to `_chkstk'
..\lib/libeay32.lib(tmp32/bio_asn1.obj):(.text[_BIO_asn1_set_prefix]+0x6): undefined reference to `_chkstk'
..\lib/libeay32.lib(tmp32/bio_asn1.obj):(.text[_BIO_asn1_get_prefix]+0x6): undefined reference to `_chkstk'
..\lib/libeay32.lib(tmp32/bio_asn1.obj):(.text[_BIO_asn1_set_suffix]+0x6): more undefined references to `_chkstk' follow
..\lib/ssleay32.lib(tmp32/ssl_lib.obj):(.text[_SSL_has_matching_session_id]+0xb): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably not. mingw's static library format is *.a.

Dynamic libraries for a given platform are standardized by the OS loader that must be able to load them.

Static libraries only have to be understood by the toolchain's linker, and are thus less cross compiler compatible. Afaik *.lib files are not even compatible across all MSVC versions.

**Added later** due to pestering comments:
Newer versions of mingw also support .lib files, but you asked your question back in '11, and then you probably wouldn't have them then.

Comment: For the downvotes: please take note that this answer is written significantly *before* the other answers.

Comment: As it is obviously outdated, you should probably consider adapting your answer. That would spare you more down votes and help people find the correct answer to their personal problem.

Comment: That would make the answer not in question to the question. If you think the thread is dated or confusing, vote to close it, and vote a more recent one up.

Comment: I don't think the thread is dated at all, just your answer. "Probably not." is just not correct anymore (for quite some time already), see Sasha's answer, which should be the accepted one. But hey, that are your downvotes, do as you like ;)

Comment: @pogojotz thank you for reminding me why I've stopped frequenting stackoverflow

Answer (score 36):

mingw also accepts libraries with a .lib extension.

For instance, a library named
    libsample.lib
must be linked as

-L  -llibsample

Reference:
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use

Comment: @Shasha Could you please help me out? I posted this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584344/linking-a-lib-file-on-windows-7

Answer (score 23):

New **mingw** versions support linking lib files. But I faced issues where *.lib* is with prefix *libxxxx.lib*. It omits the prefix lib in linking. So make it like **lib**<*name*>.*lib*

Also there are ways to convert a .lib to .a ex: [lib2a](http://code.google.com/p/lib2a/)
You can use that as well.

Comment: To fully specify a library name use `:` prefix. For example `-l:libxxxx.lib`.

Comment: On the contrary, when linking .lib files you would need to remove the **lib** prefix, e.g. `-lssl` would make the linker look for `ssl.lib`.