# Linking a .lib file on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, path, g++

I have a C++ program test.cpp and I want to link two .lib files to it(fhlib.lib and gc_lib.lib).I have the .lib files in the same folder as my .cpp program. I'm on Windows 7.

What I have tried so far is the following:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -L/Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\My Project -lfhlib
```

But I get an

```
No such file or directory error.
```

I'm sure the path is correct because I copied it from Properties->Location. But I had do delete the "C:\", because it was not compiling.

EDIT: I found this http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use.

So I tried using

```
"-I" instead of "-l"
```

But still doesn't work.I get:

```
undefined reference to 'fh_set'...
```

Comment: The `-I` option is for include paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that the lib files where compiled in VS. And I had to use the VS compiler instead of g++ and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 9):

If you're compiling with g++ on windows, I guess you're using MinGW: MinGW relies on .a libraries. When using the "-l" option, the compiler is looking for a library file with the extension .a.

Libraries in the format .lib are compiled with visual studio: you can't use it as this. Compile your libraries with MinGW if you have the sources or consider migrating your project to visual studio.

Comment: I already have my project in VS and can execute there. But Now I want to execute from the Python interface using os.systems("g++ -o ..."). There is no way I can link them using g++ or gcc ? What do you mean by the sources, the .dll files ?

Comment: If your libraries use plain C, it may be possible by passing the path to the .lib: `g++ -o main main.cpp "C:/Users/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/My Project/fhlib.lib"` (note I used quotes because of the spaces in the path and '/' instead '\' to avoid special characters misinterpretation). If your libraries use C++, there is no binary compatibility between compilers, so it shouldn't work

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. I get **undefined reference to 'fh_set'** ... Can i link them inside the cake file and then I execute os.system("make")?

Comment: Apparently MinGW now supports also <name>.lib files. http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use

Comment: MinGW supports them for years. As I said, if g++ finds your .lib binary compatible it can use it. But it will probably not. Try it: if it works, you're good. Otherwise AFAIK there is nothing to do except compile all the sources with the same compiler

Comment: How can I compile them all with the same compiler ?

Comment: I don't have the source code I only have the .dll and .lib files