# G++ linker exiting with code 1 with an undefined reference to 'vkCreateInstance'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, build, g++, vulkan

I've been having some trouble setting up a custom Vulkan build and development environment with G++ and VSCode. G++ doesn't seem to be linking to the proper library files, and is not recognizing only one of the Vulkan functions I've defined in main.cpp. That, or it's not properly finding the header files. I followed a video tutorial and did my own tweaking to make it work. (You can find it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRQ3zqCiKdQ). He creates a .bat file to run the compiler command and sets up some boilerplate tasks.json and launch.json files. The .bat file runs fine and makes it so that I don't have to type out file paths each time. Those work fine. And then I've copied his code as well just to get the build environment working, which I'm stuck on.

I'll admit, I'm not a wizard with command line compilers, but I just can't seem to find any information online that can help me. It's either outdated or the answer doesn't fix my issue. So I thought I'd try here. (first question btw).

I've got a basic, very recent and up-to-date Vulkan installation, a main.cpp file, a build.bat file, and g++ version 11.2.0 (according to MSys2, the latest version). I'm on Windows 64 bit running VSCode. I've included some in order, ending with a capture of my working directory. Afterwards, I'll list what I've tried.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.hpp>
#include <vulkan/vulkan_core.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = "Pong";
    appInfo.pEngineName = "PongEngine";

    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceInfo = {};
    instanceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    instanceInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
    
    VkInstance instance;

    VkResult result = vkCreateInstance(&instanceInfo, NULL, &instance);

    if(result == VK_SUCCESS){
        cout << "Successful!" << endl;
    }
}
```

**Build.bat**

```
@echo off

SET include=-I ./src -I C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.198.1/Include/
SET links= -L /C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.198.1/Lib/vulkan-1.lib


@echo "Building main..."


g++ -Wall %include% %links% -o main src/main.cpp
```

**Directory**

```
Root
|-----src
      |-main.cpp
|-build.bat
```

I have tried almost everything. This is always the output:

```
"Building main..."
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\brado\AppData\Local\Temp\ccj9NixH.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xabe): undefined reference to `vkCreateInstance'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process "E:\coding\vulkan\personal_vulkan_expirimenting\build.bat" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

- Despite -L supposedly specifying directories to search in, anytime I don't include `vulkan-1.lib` on the -L tag, it breaks.
- I've tried using -l to specify the specific library and that doesn't seem to work
- I feel like I've tried every flag under the sun. Someone somewhere said it might have to do with -m64 flag but that wasn't it.
- I've added in two seemingly redundant header files that I've manually searched for `vkCreateInstance` in and included them in the hopes that that would trigger it but in vain
- I've edited the file paths every which way to see if the formatting was the issue
- I have read and checked the g++ and Vulkan documentation to see if anything could help and I could find seemingly nothing that would have helped. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place. But I've been googling for hours.
- Before this whole fiasco started, I was also trying to use GLFW and GLM as per the basic Vulkan tutorial that's provided, and that was also having linking problems, which to me, narrows it down to how I'm using the compiler.

What's so confusing is that the intellisense on VS Code recognizes the function, and the linker has no issue with the other functions. It may be a limitation in my understanding of compilers, or I've tunnel-visioned and am not seeing outside the problem, I don't know. I'll admit I'm not insanely familiar with g++, but as I tried to get more familiar with it over the course of this problem (that I've been on for the last couple hours) I couldn't find any documentation Let me know what other information I can provide, maybe there's something I'm leaving out. Thanks so much!

Comment: You need `C:/VulkanSDK/1.2.198.1/Lib/vulkan-1.lib`. `-L` is for specifying the directories that `-l` will search in but i think `-lvulkan-1` won't work as it would be looking for `libvulkan-1.lib`

Comment: So the naming conventions are causing problems then, awesome. Makes sense -l wasn’t giving me the proper file.

Comment: yep, the SDK is probably written for visual studio which doesn't use that convention

Comment: Unfortunate. I know for a fact that you can get it working on VSCode, I've seen other people do it. I've already tested it and gotten it working on Visual Studio but I'm being stubborn. Not a huge fan of the working environment, even though I know it comes with benefits. I've just done some more poking around and realized the problem is that the header file needs a source code file to point to, which I need to find and link somehow. Looking into where the source code for vulkan.h would be. I'm assuming it'd be in the library file.

Comment: According to a comment on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584344/linking-a-lib-file-on-windows-7/38584536#38584536 bcc just doesn’t recognize .lib files…so I may just have to use a different compiler

Comment: I think more recent versions of mingw does support lib files. In general though on windows you are better off using the visual studio compiler

Comment: As I remember, on MinGW one has to point the linker directly to the *.dll file. (Which is in `C:\Windows\System32`).

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the feedback everyone. In that same video tutorial he sets up VSCode to use the Visual Studio compiler from the command line so I'll just get that up and running