# Moxa PComm.lib with g++ under mingw64: file format not recognized

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw-w64

I am refactoring an old Borland C/C++98 program. I would like to program it under linux platform but to beginning, as I have severals additionnals boards, I clean the program, remove all GUI OWL and make tests under win7 and mingw64 to use modern gcc/g++.

I actually try to link a sample code that use C320 turbo Moxa multiport serial board.
As mentionned in 
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use 
it should link .lib and .dll.

So I tried to link my sample with Moxa PComm.lib for sio_open, sio_read, sio_write… functions as

```
g++ -m32 -Wall -std=c++14 src/main.cpp src/rs232_c320t.cpp … -L./lib -lPComm
```

and it returns

```
./lib/PComm.lib: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

Are there any options to allow link windows .lib with gcc/g++ under mingw64?

Thanks

This related "[Linking *.lib files with MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241047/linking-lib-files-with-mingw)" question doesn't mention "File format not recognize" error. See also my comments below.

bcag2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking \*.lib files with MinGW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241047/linking-lib-files-with-mingw) Oh, and if it is an  really old .lib made for\by Borland compiler from 90s, it might be not compatible with anything but their compiler

Comment: I tried to rename the lib file without success… in fact g++ read the file but can't works with.

Comment: I tried too Lib2a wich return "invalid or corrupt import library". The last version of PComm Lite from Moxa was released in 2012-05 so I don't think it was with Borland. It is my program that was initialy wrote with Borland but it is not the issue!

Comment: if that windows app, why you port it to Linux API? And no, you can't use  window library files for mingw, because migw emulates gcc in Linux environment, it uses  GNU C++ format of binaries. You either should use Linux library, OSS or from Moxa. I would be surprised if Moxa didn't  do that). Accepted answer to THAT question is your answer

Comment: @Swift: No, *mingw* does not emulate the Linux environment.  *cygwin* does, but `mingw` is just the GNU Compiler Collection (gcc) running on windows, compiling windows programs and generating windows file formats.  The only thing that's different is the format of the debug metadata, the object file format follows Microsoft's standard (COFF, not ELF).

Comment: @Swift: I want switch to Linux because I prefer free soft than privative (so my PC run GNU/Linux and because I think to implement lamp server to push datas in data base instead of csv files. I actually make tests with [http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/] and avoid sio_ moxa functions

Comment: My tests with http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/ are OK on win7+mingw64 and on GNU/Linux too. On linux, Moxa port are viewed as ttyA11, ttyA12… after run mxinstall so I change rs232.c comports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded last [PCommLite for win7 x64](https://www.moxa.com/support/DownloadFile.aspx?type=support&id=167).

Copy `C:\Program Files\Moxa\PCommLite 1.6\Include\PCOMM.H` in my include project folder (lib in my case), and do the same for files `PCOMM.dll` and `PCOMM.lib` in `C:\Program Files\Moxa\PCommLite 1.6\Lib\x64`.

Then I compile with:

```
g++ -c -std=c++14 -D_hypot=hypot -DWIN32 src/*.cpp -I./lib/
```

Where `-I./lib` give access to `PCOMM.H` and link with:

```
g++ -shared *.o lib/PCOMM.LIB /c/Windows/System32/msvcr120.dll /c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python36.dll -o _project.pyd
```

Of course you can do all in one time and create an `.exe`:

```
g++ -o project.exe -Wall -std=c++14 -DWIN32 src/*.cpp -Ilib/ lib/PCOMM.LIB -L./lib/
```

NO `-ansi` required as suggested by Moxa support!